# Undefined reference to `Process::process_data_buffer(int, AppData*, int, int)'

Tags: c++, ns2

I am trying to run the make command in ns2 but i get this error:

`undefined reference to Process::process_data_buffer(int, AppData*, int, int)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ns] Error 1`

I am using ubuntu 10.04
any help please.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to locate the problem without sample codes.

But it is probable that the member function implemented in the .cpp file has not the same signature as declared in the .h file

Carefully check it, make sure they are the same.

Comment: the solution was make clean + make